# Geodesics on product manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic, connections

I need to prove this:

Let $(M_{1}, g)$ $(M_{2}, h)$ riemannian manifolds, consider $(M_{1} \times M_{2})$ with the product metric, and $\nabla = \nabla^{1} + \nabla^{2}$. Then $\gamma=(\gamma_{1}, \gamma_{2})$ is a geodesic $\iff$ $\gamma_{1}, \gamma_{2}$ are geodesics respectively on $M_{1}, M_{2}.$

At first look, it seemed trivial to me, but then I realised it wasn't. In fact, locally $(\dot{\gamma_{1}},0),(0, \dot{\gamma_{2}}) $ are vector fields only defined along $\gamma$ and we need to extend them near $\gamma$ to calculate $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma_{i}}}\dot{\gamma_{i}},$ $i=1,2.$ My guess was extending them so that $\dot{\gamma_{1}}, \dot{\gamma_{2}}$ are constant along $M_{2},M_{1}$ respectively. In this way, we obtain using koszul formula that $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma_{1}}}\dot{\gamma_{1}},\nabla_{\dot{\gamma_{2}}}\dot{\gamma_{2}}$ have no components along $M_{2},M_{1}$ respectively. Then we conclude using $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma}$=$\nabla^{1}_{\dot{\gamma_{1}}}\dot{\gamma_{1}}+\nabla^{2}_{\dot{\gamma_{2}}}\dot{\gamma_{2}}$.
Do you think I did it right?

Comment: This you do before discussing geodesics: Given a connection $\nabla$, for a vector field $V$ along a curve $c$ you define the covariant derivative $\frac{D}{dt}V$ of $V$ along $c$. This will be discussed pretty much in any textbook on the subject, for instance, do Carmo. So, no need to worry about the extension problem at the later stage.